# Should I attach my resume and cover letter as 2 separate files or combine them into a single file?

Tags: resume, job-search, email, cover-letter

I am using online job portals to search for suitable opportunities. I think that, since the website is visited by several employers, there is no point in uploading a cover letter to the website's database as the cover letter must be customized for individual organization.

However, when I apply for a particular position in a company, I attach my resume and cover letter as two separate PDF documents. Is it better to combine them into a single PDF file with the first page being the cover letter followed by the resume?
Or should I send them as two separate documents?

Comment: see also: [Can emails count as being cover letters, or should a cover letter be a proper document?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/104623/can-emails-count-as-being-cover-letters-or-should-a-cover-letter-be-a-proper-do)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a job portal, you should probably only be uploading your resume.

If there is a section of the portal for personal information including the types of roles you are looking for, make sure you fill that out completely. Also ensure you have a very brief general summary statement at the top of your resume.

If you are emailing the company, just send the email as the cover letter and attach the resume.

Answer (score 3):

**Provide your resume and cover letter as separate files.** Two files with names like “Resume.pdf” and “Cover letter.pdf” make clear to a recruiter or manager reviewing the application that both were provided.